# request.getContextPath in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building an Single-Page-Application where the front end is using ReactJS, and React Router.

The application shall be hosted with conventional app server either Tomcat or Weblogic (just due to whatever reason as required by our client).

My question is straight forward: in React, how could I get the application context path which is equivalent to request.getContextPath() as in jsp? I did many searching in google, but none of it could just give me a straight to the point answer. Whether react having such equivalent function? Or if I could grab this path from JSP? If so, how to grab it?

Thanks.

Comment: react is a front end framework and so wouldn't be able to get this kind of information about the server side context.

Comment: The "context path" is a concept specific for .war files on a Java appllcation server. It has no influence on your react frontend app. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Please be more specific, put an example of what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far

Comment: Hi, what I am trying to achieve is: I am going to use the "axios" to query the server for whatever data, and I would like to use the the absolute path (http://localhost:8080/myapp/myapi?...) instead of relevant path (/myapi?...). And note that my SPA may not be directly pathed as http://localhost:8080/myapp/spa, it could be http://localhost:8080/myapp/xxx/yyy/spa. So in such scenarios, how could I able to get this http://localhost:8080/myapp value without hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and solved it like this:

In reactjs, when you are building your app for production, you need to run "npm run build".

To build it correctly, you need to set the homepage property in package.json to the main url of your site.

In my case I am using http://localhost:3000 for local development, and http://localhost:8080/myapp for stage testing.

That app needs to know if there is a "myapp" in the url or not. This is basically the problem of this post.

My answer is, because you need to specify the homepage property in package.json anyway, I am using this value to find my context path.

I am doing this like this:
{packageJson.homepage.substring(packageJson.homepage.lastIndexOf("/"))+"/login"}

For my test environment this returns: /login
For my stage environment this returns: /myapp/login

Maybe this helps.